# FROM preg_replace TO preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, deprecated, preg-replace-callback

Hello fellow netheads!

I'm having issues with updating some old function to preg_replace_callback.
Edit: what am I doing wrong?

This is my first (preg_replace/deprecated) function:

```
if ($handle) {
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
    @eval('$templ = new '.TEMPL_CLASS.';');
    $buffer = preg_replace("#§([a-z0-9-_]+)\.?([a-z0-9-_]+)?#ie","\$templ->\\1(\\2)",$buffer);
    $out .= $buffer;
    }
fclose($handle);
}
```

Second function (this is my attempt at converting to preg_replace_callback):

```
if ($handle) {
  while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
    @eval('$templ = new '.TEMPL_CLASS.';');  
    $buffer = preg_replace_callback(
      '#§([\w-]+)\.?([\w-]+)?#',
      function ($m) {
        @$templ->$m[1]($m[2]);   
      },
      $buffer
    );
    $out .= $buffer;
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
```

OLD! M42's answear fixed the follow error:

> Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Modifier /e cannot be used with
>   replacement callback in /var/www/inc/engine.php on line 52

```
); <-- line 52
$out .= $buffer;
```

Edit: I dont know how to handle the render part of this..

```
$buffer = preg_replace("#§([a-z0-9-_]+)\.?([a-z0-9-_]+)?#ie","\$templ->\\1(\\2)",$buffer);
```

Right now it is rendering a blank page.. I guess the error is in

> return templ($m[1], $m[2]);

Comment: Sorry, what is the question?

Comment: Oh, thanks for noticing!
I don't know what I'm doing wrong in my attempt (the second codeblock)

Comment: OK, are you getting errors? If so what are they? Please add them to the question, it will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Sorry.. I just added the error to my original post :) thank you for taking your time with my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it's said in the message, removed the `e` modifier:

```
'#§\\(\\[a-z0-9-_\\]+\\)\.?\\(\\[a-z0-9-_\\]+\\)?#i'
//                                         here ___^
```

And there're no needs to escape all these characters:

```
'#§([a-z0-9_-]+)\.?([a-z0-9_-]+)?#i'
```

`[a-z0-9_]` can be rewritten `\w` and there're no needs to `i` modifier

```
'#§([\w-]+)\.?([\w-]+)?#'
```

The whole instruction becomes:

```
$buffer = preg_replace_callback(
  '#§([\w-]+)\.?([\w-]+)?#',
  function ($m) {
    return templ($m[1], $m[2]);
  },
  $buffer
);
```

Comment: That worked fine! Atleast it threw me a new error.. Sorry I cant vote you up just yet, I need more rep

Comment: Now it throws me: 
Warning: preg_replace_callback() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given in /var/www/inc/engine.php on line 52

Comment: @mlv: I've edited with the whole instruction. It works pretty fine for me. May be you're using it wrong.

Comment: Thank you! It wasnt working because I was trying to return templ as a variable instead of a function 
...
return @templ
...

Comment: This doesnt solve the issue tho, just that error (thank you for helping me with that)